# Chat Log in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, performance, data-binding, chat

I have an application with a chat log, the ChatService is injected into the controller and is used to store an array of messages.

Within' my view, I'm using ng-repeat to render out the messages but this is creating 3-4 watchers for each line of text which in turn is creating performance issues anytime I update something on the page. As the chat log/number of watchers grows, the performance gets worse.

I don't want to push the messages onto the DOM as a string as I need to be able to show/hide timestamps and remove messages and doing this would get rid of the bindings which allow those actions.

Are there any alternative approaches that I'm overlooking? What would be the suggested way to handle this situation?

Comment: Have you tried using bind-once? to the data since the messages will not be update individually? http://toddmotto.com/angular-one-time-binding-syntax/